# sbt installation on an offline windows machine

Tags: scala, sbt

I have an offline windows machine that previously had sbt 0.13.X installed that know one remembers how we installed it in the first place.
We decided to upgrade that machines sbt to 1.3.3 but since the machine is offline it wont work giving us the following error:

```
"Unresolved Dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt 1.3.3 not found"
```

I have tried dropping the "local-preloaded" folder contents to the .ivy2 "local" folder, with no difference. I did exactly the same on an online pc and it worked as expected.

I made sure our build.proprties sbt.version was ok:

```
sbt.version=1.3.3
```

The code can't be moved to an online computer so it's unfortunately not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Sbt uses two folders for caching dependencies ~/.ivy2 and ~/.sbt. If you move both folders from an online pc to the offline pc it should actually work.